# Equivalent Cisco EEM in Huawei

Tags: cisco, switch, huawei, cisco-eem

is there a Huawei feature works similar than Cisco EEM?? I want to shutdown an interface when a track goes down

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your device model. 
For instance CE (cloud engine) switches, AR and N40 routers are supporting OPS technology (Open Programming System). OPS is quite similar to Cisco EEM and, in addition, it might be able to process python scripts.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think they are supporting this feature at the moment. And you can always check this with local Huawei Support/Sales team.